# Multiple `(으)시` in a sentence for honoring target?

Tags: verb-endings, honorific, adjective-endings

I find that I am anxious about **making sure to honor the person that I'm speaking about, especially if they are the person I am speaking to** or are of a high position.

Take this interrogative sentence spoken to someone revered:

> Are you, teacher, the one who sent it?
>
> 이것을 보낸 분 입니까?

I have purposefully left out the honorific final ending to the two verbs *(one functioning as an adjective, of course)*.

Here are the options for including `(으)시`:

> 이것을 보낸 분 이십니까?
>
> 이것을 보내신 분 이십니까?

I usually end up over conjugating and using the latter...I would be grateful for some **guidance, not just on what people tend to do, but what is the most honorific and/or what is beyond honorific** headed into nonsensical.

**update**

In general I find that as my mind is constructing a sentence that does not require honoring someone, I can speak rather fluently.  When it comes to the final verb conjugation, that too, I do well.

The verb-conjugation-adjectives (if I may coin a dumb phrase) trip me up; because, **I have to literally pause and get a picture in my mind of the *direction* of each adjective phrase to figure out to whom it applies and calculate whether or not to add honor to them**.

I typically am speaking Korean at church where business-speak is probably in play a good bit, but that is not the air with wich I wish to speak.

Comment: I made the change from 선생님은 to 선생님이 at the suggestion of a native Korean, who said that 선생님은 isn't "pointing" enough when asking who the actor is. I'm not sure I'm quite clear on the reason myself though -   i'd have to ask another question!

Comment: I would say that final 시 is more important.  Just using 입니까 would be rude, I think.

Comment: @topomorto - thx, 은는/이가 is like an ambidextrous fighter that always counters with the opposite hook that i intend to block with. many black eyes.

Comment: I see that my former answer was not on point. Your new example sentence won't work, but changing it slightly 주문하신 분이세요 or 전화하신 분이세요 would be typical; 전화하신 분이십니까 is more respect and the limit of ordinary speech. To go beyond it (and into the absurd) would require archaic forms.

Comment: i'll have to come up with a better example, it may take some time.  i was trying to keep it clinical, small in nature.  but in this case, i would not stumble, so it's not a good example.  when there are multiple adjective conjugates within clauses before the final verb conjugation, that is when it gets hairy, and i suppose i'm simply wondering to what degree every thing referring to the honored person must be conjugated with the 으시다 in it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've been told that essentially the more (으)시's you put in, the more polite you're being. As with English, if you go super-polite, you might be in danger of over-egging the pudding, or sounding insincere - but it will still make sense.

One '(으)시' is enough to show politeness:

> 선생님이 보내신 분 입니까?
>
> 선생님이 보낸 분 이십니까?

If you wanted to level up the politeness, the next step would be to make sure you use the honorific subject particle:

> 선생님**께서** 보내신 분 입니까?
>
> 선생님**께서** 보낸 분 이십니까?

The ultimate in politeness would be

> 선생님께서 보내신 분 이십니까?

That might be appropriate if a parent was asking the teacher the question in front of her child, for example, 'demonstrating' politeness. It might be a bit much if said by a colleague of the teacher with only themselves and the teacher present.

As a more general point, you don't need to worry too much about getting the politeness level every sentence exactly right - often the speech level can even vary a bit over the course of a dialogue. From what I've noticed, the most important thing to get right is the honorific forms of verbs (드시다 instead of 먹다, 주무시다 instead of 자다, etc.) Though I make mistakes all the time, the only time a Korean has actually corrected my politeness level was when I offered someone some food and invited them to "먹으세요"!

Comment: Genuine question (I'm a learner, obviously)... what was wrong with saying "먹으세요"?